# Groups of order $8n$ have at least five distinct conjugacy classes

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

It was brought to my attention by [Kevin Dong](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/149792/kevin-dong) that every finite group whose order is a multiple of 8 must have at least five distinct conjugacy classes. This can be seen as follows:

If $|G| = 8n$, then $$8n = \sum_{\text{irreps of G}} (\text{dim}(V))^2 = 1 + \sum_{\text{nontrivial irreps of G}} (\text{dim}(V))^2$$

Using that perfect squares are always $0$, $1$, or $4$ $\pmod{8}$, a little casework shows there must be at least four nontrivial irreducible representations of $G$. Hence, there are at least five conjugacy classes.

How could one prove this without using any representation theory?

Comment: Wouldn't the conjugacy class equation give you a similar answer?   http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class#Conjugacy_class_equation

Comment: it can be found by examining some cases, I may write the answer later.

Answer (score 2):

#### Proof in the case $n$ is odd

By [Sylow's 1st theorem](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/sylowpf.pdf) there is a subgroup $H \vartriangleleft G$ of order (at least) **2 × 2  × 2 = 8**.  This could be one of [five](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_8) possibilities:

- $\mathbb{Z}_8, \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2, \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and additionally
- $ D_8 \simeq \mathbb{Z}_4 \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2, Q = (\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2 $.  The  [dihedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group) and [quaternion group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group).

In the Abelian case, it is clear there are eight conjugacy classes - 1 for each element.  Since $H$ is [**normal**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1216799/is-a-conjugacy-class-of-a-subgroup-a-conjugacy-class-of-the-whole-group), these extend to conjugacy classes of $G$.

In the Dihedral case, the rotations form a normal subgroup: $\mathbb{Z}_4 \vartriangleleft D_8 $.  This leads to 4 conjugacy classes + 2 for the reflections.  These are the symmetries of a square (See **[List all subgroups of the symmetry group of $n$-gon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108457/list-all-subgroups-of-the-symmetry-group-of-n-gon?rq=1)**).

The quaternion group $\langle i,j,k | i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = ijk=-1\rangle$ has [**6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group) conjugacy classes.

---

Representation theory makes it as simple as the [sumset](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327450/what-are-the-bounds-upper-and-lower-for-aa) identity ($7$ is missing):
$$ \{ 0^2,1^2,2^2\} + \{ 0^2,1^2,2^2\} + \{ 0^2,1^2,2^2\} \subset \{0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$$
Sylow theorem guaranteed us a large enough normal subgroup; this is clearly the way to go.

The problem is reduced to the detailed study of the partitions and permutations involves the number 8 and related coincidences.

Comment: I am probably missing something, but how do you use Sylow's first theorem to prove $H$ is a *normal* subgroup?

Comment: @JasonDeVito **Third** Sylow theorem says the *maximal* Sylow $p$-group is normal.  I stand corrected.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still not sure why the maximal Sylow $p$-group is normal.  What about a simple group, like $A_n$ ($n\geq 5$)?  Such a group has order $n!/2$ which is of the form $8k$ once $n \geq 6$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito OK.  There could be any odd number of Sylow 2-groups, all conjugate to each other, which intersect each other in interesting ways.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, it turns out that there are only finitely many finite groups with a given number of conjugacy classes. This is not hard to prove and it's not too hard to find all of them with up to four conjugacy classes, say:
http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/There_are_finitely_many_finite_groups_with_bounded_number_of_conjugacy_classes