# What are the bounds (upper and lower) for $|A+A|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, asymptotics, estimation, sumset

Let $A$ be a finite set of real (or complex) numbers. If I consider sets with small  sizes, we have that:

1. If $A$ is the empty set, then $A+A$ is also empty.
2. If $A$ is a singleton, then $A+A$ is also a singleton.
3. If $|A|=2,$ then $|A+A|=3.$
4. If $|A|=3,$ then $|A+A|$ can be at most $6.$
   The set $A=\{1, 2, 3\}$ shows we can have that $|A+A|=5,$ But we can not obtain $4.$

Obvious bounds for $A+A$ are $|A|\le |A+A|\le|A|^2.$
But for large $|A|$ values, it looks like that we can find more sharpe bounds for $|A+A|$ than above ones.

MY QUESTION IS: How can I estimate the size of the set $A+A=\{a+b :a,b\in A\}$ using the size of $A$ ?

Comment: Your bound is not correct. You can get way more than $2|A|$ elements (consider what happens if all sums are distinct apart from the order).

Comment: Thanks. I have just edit it. Is it correct?

Comment: Now you can do slightly better for the bound, as a binomial coefficient.

Comment: I did not get it. Can you explain it more?

Comment: Since addition is commutative, you can at most get $|A|+1$ choose $2$ distinct sums.

Comment: So upper bound should be $\dfrac{|A|(|A|+1)}{2}$ ?

Comment: Yes, and that bound is sharp.

Comment: BTW, in general sets like these can be hard to get a hold on. See for example http://mathoverflow.net/questions/204020/is-the-set-aaa-always-at-least-as-large-as-aa

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thank you. How about lower bound?

Comment: $2|A| - 1 \le |A+A| \le \frac{|A|(|A|+1)}{2}$

Comment: For real numbers, write the elements in order, $a_1 < a_2 < \dotsc < a_n$. You have the $n$ elements $\{a_1 + a_k : 1 \leqslant k \leqslant n\}$. How many new elements has the set $\{ a_2 + a_k : 1 \leqslant k \leqslant n\}$ give you _at least?_ Continue for a (sharp) lower bound. For complex numbers, take e.g. lexicographic ordering to get the same lower bound.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Why do not you post your comment as an answer. I think, this is the explanation which I look for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For general finite subsets of abelian groups we have
$$
|A| \leq |A + A| \leq \frac{|A|(|A| + 1)}{2}
$$

In the case of $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$, we are dealing with torsion-free abelian groups (i.e. they have no finite subgroups) we have a lower bound of $2|A| - 1$, which is attained if and only if $A$ is an arithmetic progression, i.e. $A = \{a,\, a + d,\, a + 2d, \dots,\, a + (N-1)d\}$ for $N = |A|$ and numbers $a, d$.

The upper bound is sharp and occurs if and only if all pairwise sums in $A$ are distinct ($A$ is then called a Sidon set). This happens often in $\mathbb R$ (and $\mathbb C$): for example, if you choose a set of $N$ numbers uniformly random from $[0, 1]$ you will get a Sidon set with probability 1.

Comment: I found [this.](https://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwj9qPjJopbGAhWBe6YKHRPrDMs&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSidon_sequence&ei=ZiqBVf3dLIH3mQWT1rPYDA&usg=AFQjCNFd1UcRLNix_eysN1xCq7rD9J5JDA) and [this.](https://people.math.osu.edu/glasscock.4/MSThesis.pdf) Thank you. Great answer.

Comment: Glad it helped! If you're interested in more of this, I can highly recommend the book [Additive Combinatorics](http://www.cambridge.org/nl/academic/subjects/mathematics/real-and-complex-analysis/additive-combinatorics?format=PB) by Terence Tao and Van H. Vu.